# gflags full page heap seems not effective?

Tags: security, heap-memory, reverse-engineering, windbg, gflags

Help me!! I am really worrying about this problem, It's about my tomorrow's homework.
I use `gflags /p /enable AcroRd32.exe /full` to enable AcroRd32.exe with full page,however it doesn't work. AS the following photo showing:
in the same page there are two heap block which are configured toful page heap, why is it?
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Use gflags with the same same bittness (32/64) as your AcroRd32.exe
Try with gui mode of gflags (just double click)
Go to Image File tab, enter .exe name (no path) hit tab.
[image]